# How to separate the color maps in plotly

Tags: python, plotly, plotly.graph-objects

Currently, I have a plot with 2 scatter plots. I have done this using graph_objects in plotly using the append_trace method. But the color scale of the 2 plots are overlapping as shown in the figure.[image: Figure]
I have also tried adding the plots in 2 rows instead of columns but the problem still persists.
How do separate the 2 color scales?

Code for adding the plots:

```
fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2)
fig.append_trace(go.Scatter(x=X1, y=Y1, mode='markers', marker=dict(
    color=C1,
    colorscale='Viridis',
    showscale=True
)), row=1, col=1)
fig.append_trace(go.Scatter(x=X, y=Y2, mode='markers', marker=dict(
    color=C2,
    colorscale='Viridis',
    showscale=True
)), row=1, col=2)
fig.show()
```

Comment: Add color bar position to marker settings. `colorbar=dict(x=0.45)` See previous [responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73834595/adding-colorbar-to-a-scatterplot-1-panels-generated-through-add-scatter).

Answer (score 0):

Adding a colorbar to the marker setting worked for me.

Updated code:

```
fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2)
fig.append_trace(go.Scatter(x=X1, y=Y1, mode='markers', marker=dict(
    color=C1,
    colorscale='Viridis',
    showscale=True,
    colorbar=dict(x=0.45)
)), row=1, col=1)
fig.append_trace(go.Scatter(x=X, y=Y2, mode='markers', marker=dict(
    color=C2,
    colorscale='Viridis',
    showscale=True
)), row=1, col=2)
fig.show()
```